# How to Retrieve Data from Node Server With Socket?

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io, real-time-data

i've got problem getting data from Node server, i've searching many reference from internet, but i haven't found one yet that can solve my problem.
this is my node server

```
var socket  = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
/*
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('cert/file.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/file.crt')
};
var server  = require('https').createServer(options, app);
*/
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//server.listen(port, '103.126.57.4', function () {
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
    //console.log('Server listening at port %d', port, server.address());
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {

console.log( "New client connected !" );
//console.log(socket.handshake.headers.host);

socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( 'new_message', {
        idleveluser: data.idleveluser,
        nama: data.nama,
        level: data.level,
        idchat: data.idchat,
        pesan: data.pesan,
        file: data.file,
        reply: data.reply,
        created_at: data.created_at
    });
});

socket.on( 'new_chat_kelas', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( data.tabelchat, {
        idleveluser: data.idleveluser,
        nama: data.nama,
        level: data.level,
        idchat: data.idchat,
        pesan: data.pesan,
        file: data.file,
        reply: data.reply,
        created_at: data.created_at
    });
});

socket.on( 'change_chat_status', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( 'change_status'+data.tabelchat, {
        status: data.status
    });
});

/*
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log( "Client disconnected !" );
});
*/});
```

And this is my Android code

```
try {
//if you are using a phone device you should connect to same local network as your laptop and disable your pubic firewall as well
        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.100.13:3000");
        socket.connect();

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    refreshChat(url);
    getTabelKelas();
    getDiskusiChat(sharedDiskusi.getSpdiskusi());


private void getDiskusiChat(String tabelChat) {
    socket.on(tabelChat, new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    String jsonStr = data.toString();
                    Log.d("cek", "cek data : "+data);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, (CharSequence) data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        //extract data from fired event
                        String cek = String.valueOf(data.getJSONArray("idleveluser"));
//                            String nickname = data.getString("senderNickname");
//                            String message = data.getString("message");

                            // make instance of message
//
//                            Message m = new Message(nickname,message);
//                            Message m = new Message(nickname,message);
//
//
//                            //add the message to the messageList
//
//                            MessageList.add(m);
//
//                            // add the new updated list to the dapter
//                            chatBoxAdapter = new ChatBoxAdapter(MessageList);
//
//                            // notify the adapter to update the recycler view
//
//                            chatBoxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//
//                            //set the adapter for the recycler view
//
//                            myRecylerView.setAdapter(chatBoxAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

i have try to Toast and log it but did not appear.
Can anyone help me to retrieve data ?I confuse how to get data if the data in the form of an array. I'm helped if someone helps me. 
Sry for my bad english brother.

This is my log
[image]

Comment: 'tabelChat' this must your key name matching to to emitted method.

Comment: the value tabelChat already matching to emitted method bro, i already display it in Toast to check it

Answer (score 0):

Change this code line

```
String cek = String.valueOf(data.getJSONArray("idleveluser"));
```

to

```
String cek = String.valueOf(data.getString("idleveluser"));
```

as each item in the data object is a string.

Comment: i can't get data from JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0]; bro, i Toast and log it but didn't appear

Comment: i'll post the log bro wait.

Comment: i already post it bro, but Log.d("cek", "cek data : "+data); didn't appear

Comment: this means your socket message has not triggered yet or not received at the device side.

Comment: but in web it can receive data bro.

Comment: my wrong bro, i set socket.emit after send message, that make socket.on work after it.